# Integration of Gaussian's

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need to find the integration of
$$
\operatorname{G}\left(x\right) =
\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,
\exp\left(\frac{\left[1 - y^{2}\right]^2}{4a}\right) \int_{y}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,
\exp\left(-\,\frac{\left[1 - z^{2}\right]^{2}}{4a}\right)
$$
for $a > 0$.

I have tried to do it a lot of times but could not get it.

Answer (score 0):

we have $z\in[y,\infty),y\in[0,x]$ which is the same as:
$$0\le z<\infty,0<y<x$$
minus a triangular region at the bottom i.e.
$$G(x)=\int_0^x\int_0^\infty e^{\frac{(1-y^2)^2-(1-z^2)^2}{4a}}dzdy-\int_0^x\int_0^ye^{\frac{(1-y^2)^2-(1-z^2)^2}{4a}}dzdy$$

if you were to try something like converting to polar coordinates with:
$$z=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$$
then you can try some manipulations:
$$(1-y^2)^2-(1-z^2)^2$$
$$=(1-r^2\sin^2\theta)^2-(1-r^2\cos^2\theta)^2$$
$$=\left(1-2r^2\sin^2\theta+r^4\sin^4\theta\right)-\left(1-2r^2\cos^2\theta+r^4\cos^4\theta\right)$$
$$=2r^2\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)+r^4\left(\sin^4\theta-\cos^4\theta\right)$$
now we need to try and use some manipulations:
$$\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=\cos2\theta$$
$$\sin^4\theta-\cos^4\theta=\left(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\right)\left(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta\right)=-\cos2\theta$$
and so:
$$(1-y^2)^2-(1-z^2)^2=2r^2\cos2\theta-r^4\cos2\theta=r^2(2-r^2)\cos2\theta$$
Although neither of these give nice integrals and so i'd assume that if changing the order of integration doesn't work then change of variables will be the only way

Comment: Even after simplification, it looks difficult to solve. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. That rules out polar coordinates

Comment: Can you help me simplifying this?